# Window Guard Problems

Tags: windows, window-frame, air

I have an extension cord inside my house that is feeding outside via a window. I currently just have a towel blocking the air that’s coming in. Any recommendations for a more commercial, more permanent guard to block the cold air from coming in?

I’ve looked into regular weather strips and they are all too small for the space.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `extension cord inside my house that is feeding outside via a window` ... sounds very dangerous ... is it plugged into a GFCI outlet?

Comment: What are you powering with this extension cord?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. You'll note that shopping advice questions are [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you'd care to [edit] your question to ask about how to solve the "extension cord through a window" dilemma, then feel free to [edit] to ask a different question. In the meantime, plug the extension cord into an outside outlet. Close the window.

Answer (score 1):

Running an extension cord through an exterior window is a severe code violation.  The only way to expect any leniency on this is if you're using that extension cord for a very short time  during the installation of exterior receptacles.  After that, you must use the exterior receptacles.

The more commercial and permanent solution is to install exterior receptacles and shut the window.